# How and when did Uchiha Madara learn Edo Tensei?

Tags: naruto

During the Fourth Ninja World War, Uchiha Madara manage to escape Edo Tensei by releasing himself and put himself in Edo Tensei again. But how or when did Madara knew about the hand seals of Edo Tensei?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not really stated how and when Madara learned to use ET.

But it is possible that during the battles between Senju and Uchiha, Madara had seen Tobirama use it. And since ET is not a bloodline jutsu, and Madara as top Uchiha ninja, he copied it with Sharingan's ability.

Comment: With all the crazy power-ups it got, people forgot that the Sharingan was originally used to copy techniques :P

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways he could have learned it:

1. Copying it from Tobirama
2. Figuring it out himself
3. Getting the information from a different source, like a scroll. Orochimaru learned ET from the scroll of forbidden jutsus.

There is no definite answer however. It has never been stated or shown how Madara learned ET.

Answer (score -3):

I might have a more satisfying answer to this. After all Madara already awakened Rinnegan. And I think I heard Jiraiya or someone say that the specialty of Rinnegan is that it grants the Rinnegan user the ability of knowing every jutsu in existence. So of course he knows every jutsu. Simple logic, Right?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).